# Does celery chain require a result backend?

Tags: celery

The [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html) on canvas workflow seems to suggest that only chord requires a result backend. So if I am only using chain, I don't need one - is this correct?

(My chained task never seems to fire and I can't figure out why, so I am trying to double-check my assumptions.)

Comment: No, you do not need a backend for chaining.

Comment: `group` chained together will be automatically converted into `chord`, in that case you do require a result backend.

Comment: Write actual answers, not just comments, please...!